# Is there any way i can only submit the specific value from form?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form with 3 fields in this scenario I need to submit the one field value from form to spreadsheet it's working fine when I submit with all input fields but when I tried to submit only one value the error has come. The error line is "An invalid form control with name='data[value2]' is not focusable".

```
<input type="number" min="0" class="input-f" name="data[value1]" >
<input type="number" min="0" class="input-f" name="data[value2]" >
<input type="number" min="0" class="input-f" name="data[value3]" >

    fetch(form.action, {
      method : "POST",
      body: new FormData(document.getElementById("myForm"))
  }).then(
      response => response.json()
  ).then((html) => {   
    alert('Data has been submit')
```

});

Now how can I only send value1 on form submit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either make the other fields as disabled in html, or when you submit a form, use JavaScript preventDefault function and make the fields disabled and then fetch the form. If you need more details about JavaScript implementation, comment here. I will write the code for you